# How to add alternative text to table using API in Only Office

Tags: javascript, document, onlyoffice

In only office editor, there is option in advance setting of table/image /chart to set **alternative text** for the object.

We are looking for API method to set alternative text to table in document editor of onlyoffice using javascript.  I refered to Only Office ApI documentation for table and other objects [here](https://api.onlyoffice.com/docbuilder/textdocumentapi/apidocument/getdefaulttextpr) but couldn't find any solution.

Please let us know is there any way to add alternative text to table in document editor using javascript in .net